# Domain registrar saying they cannot add TXT record

Tags: domains, domain-registration, cpanel, nameserver

I have been adding SPF records to the sites I host on my VPS.

I create the record in each accounts CPanel, then add it as a TXT records in that account's related DNS registrars control panel.

However, one DNS registrar says it cannot add the record. They say 'Any changes to DNS records such as TXT records will have to be done via those nameservers, which we have no access to'.

I am not really sure what they mean or how this is meant to work. Since they host the domain name, shouldnt they be able to add a TXT or A or MX record?

Have I missed something? Is there another way to go about this?

Comment: Are you sure your DNS is hosted with your registrar? I have my domains at GoDaddy, but my DNS is with Linode, for example. Have a look at what your nameservers are set to, and this will show you where your DNS is hosted.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're not using the nameservers of your registrar.

Ask your registrar, probably through its web-interface for domain details, which company controls the nameservers for the domain name in question.  (You could also use a service like http://who.is/ to do the same check, look under *Name Servers* after providing your domain name.)

Then go to the said company that's mentioned under *Name Servers* for your domain, and ask them how to add TXT and/or SPF records to your domain name, since they're the ones who control those nameservers, and not your registrar.

Answer (score 2):

> However, one DNS registrar says it cannot add the record.

DNS registrar? Or domain registrar? Many places that offer domain registration offer DNS services, but these services are two different things entirely. When I got tired of dealing with DNS/domain issues like this I signed up for [Amazon Route 53](http://aws.amazon.com/route53/) and have been happy ever since.

To use a non-domain registrar DNS service, you have to make a one-time change to your domain registration to point to your domain to the new DNS services DNS servers. Once you do that, your DNS service—such as Amazon Route 53—is the place where you control all records.

This is the best solution I have found to the whole world of domain registrar DNS inconsistencies.

Answer (score 1):

Some registrars do not allow direct editing to their name servers and will only support common records such as in-house mx records, a records etc. I'm surprised that SPF is not one of those but there's little point asking for additional help from them. Your best bet would be to move your domain to a better registrar that has better DNS editing functions. GoDaddy, Gandi just to name a few.